# Escondendo componente no Angular 7

Tags: angular

Boa noite pessoal! Comecei a estudar Angular recentemente e me deparei com um problema que não consigo resolver, preciso que ao clicar em um botão dentro do componente header, o componente banner seja escondido.

Esta é a estrutura do app.component.html:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-banner></app-banner>
```

Este é o componente Header.html:

```
<div class="header">
   <button>Entrar</button>
</div>
```

Este é o componente Banner.html

```
<div>
  <p>banner works!</p>
</div>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa trabalhar com a comunicação entre os componentes. Primeiro você emite um evento pelo `app-header`, após isso, receberemos o valor emitido no componente pai (AppComponent) e depois o enviamos para o componente `app-banner`.

Veja em funcionamento no Stackblitz: https://angular-emk7hj.stackblitz.io

**app.component.html**

```
<app-banner [enable]="enable"></app-banner>
<app-header (buttonClick)="handleButtonClick($event)"></app-header>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  enable:boolean = false;

  handleButtonClick(value) {
    this.enable = value;
  }

}
```

**banner.component.html**

```
<p *ngIf="enable">
banner works!
</p>
```

**banner.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-banner',
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner.component.css']
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() enable:boolean;

}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<div class="header">
   <button (click)="displayBanner()">Entrar</button>
</div>
```

**header.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() buttonClick = new EventEmitter()
  enable:boolean = false;

  displayBanner(){
    this.enable = this.enable == false ? true : false;
    this.buttonClick.emit(this.enable);
  }

}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno renanzin!

Comment: mas esta apresentando erros no console

Comment: ERROR in src/app/banner/banner.component.ts(8,14): error TS2420: Class 'BannerComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'OnInit'.
  Property 'ngOnInit' is missing in type 'BannerComponent'.
src/app/banner/banner.component.ts(10,4): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Input'.
src/app/header/header.component.ts(10,14): error TS2420: Class 'HeaderComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'OnInit'.

Comment: Property 'ngOnInit' is missing in type 'HeaderComponent'.
src/app/header/header.component.ts(12,4): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Output'.
src/app/header/header.component.ts(12,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'EventEmitter'.

Comment: sabe me dizer onde errei?

Comment: Você está importando a interface OnInit?

Comment: `import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: esta assim: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

Comment: esta importado da forma acima em cada componente

Comment: pelos menos nos dois que estão dando erros a importação esta assim

Comment: Output e EventEmitter parece que não está sendo importado

Comment: estes não importei, como faço por favor?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88806/discussion-between-renanzin-and-munir-baarini).